# Trying to block extension access with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a php website on xampp, and i want to block the url access to .js and .sql files with .htaccess. While I tried to use this part of code it worked.

```
<Files something.php>
deny from all
</Files>
```

When i switched my extension to .sql or js.. it didn't. Example:

```
<Files something.js>
deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you don't only want to block the file called "something", but all files with .sql and .js?

That should work for you:

```
<Files ~ "\.js$">
Deny from all
</Files>
<Files ~ "\.sql$">
Deny from all
</Files>
```

If this causes problems, posting the contents of your apache error.log and access.log could be helpful!

Comment: I just found out that problem is in browser. On safari and chrome works well but in firefox don't.

Comment: What does not work exactly? You have a file called "something.sql" on your server which opens in the browser if you open it? Can you also post your virtual host configuration for the domain you are testing on?

Comment: alright - I just saw your comment which was posted briefly before mine. I am still curious, what happens in firefox? Does it maybe show cached files? If so, try a "hard refresh" with CTRL + F5.